# Networkx, Edge label in self loop not printed.

Tags: python, networkx

I am creating a multigraph to support self-loops. While labeling the edges, somehow the self-loop labels are not printing. In the code below, the self loop label is missing on node 'aa'

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.utils import is_list_of_ints, flatten
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G=nx.MultiGraph()

G.add_edge('aa','bb',weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('aa','cc',weight=0.2)
G.add_edge('cc','dd',weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('aa','aa',weight=0.3)


plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), facecolor="w", frameon=False)
pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G, prog="fdp") #calculate position (x,y) coordinates

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=1200,node_shape='o',node_color='0.75')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos, width=2,edge_color='b')

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,fontsize=2, labelloc='c')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos, {('aa', 'aa'):'lllllabel', ('aa', 'bb'):'aaaaaabbbbbb'}, label_pos=0.3, ax=None, rotate=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) can draw graphs with self-loops.  NetworkX [integrates with pygraphviz](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_agraph), so you might be able to use that.