# NetworkX: How to draw label nodes/edges with tex symbols?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, graphviz, networkx

Very simple, I am trying to plot a simple state-machine like this:

[image]

I am open to any form of plotting that allows for flexibility around such a plot.

This is what I have so far:

```
import networkx as nx
from nxpd import draw
G = nx.MultiDiGraph(with_labels=False,rankdir='LR')
G.graph['dpi'] = 120
G.add_node(1,label=r"$\sigma_1$",shape = 'circle')
G.add_node(2,label=r"$\sigma_2$",shape = 'circle')
G.add_edge(1,1,headport='nw',tailport='sw',label='sp')
G.add_edge(2,2,headport='se',tailport='ne')
G.add_edge(1,2,label='1-sp')
draw(G, show='ipynb')
```

Which obviously is a far cry from what I'm trying to do.

Several things are not working:

- The `headport='nw',tailport='sw'` is doing strange things
- Obviously, `r"$\sigma_2$"` is not outputting the desired tex based symbols.

**How can I plot a graph that looks like the above?**

- [Using matplotlib won't allow self-loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606313/networkx-directed-graph-no-weights-and-self-arc)

Trying to achieve the same with matplotlib and networkx

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

%matplotlib inline

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()
pos = {0:(100,100),1:(0,0)}
G.add_node(0)
G.add_node(1)
G.add_edge(0,0)
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(1,0)

labels={}
labels[0]=r'$\sigma_1$'
labels[1]=r'$\sigma_2$'
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show() # display
```

Which, for some reason, outputs a blank screen?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `nxpd` (and `import nxpd` doesn't work for me, so I don't have it on my computer), so I'm using the `nx` commands.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiDiGraph(with_labels=False,rankdir='LR')
G.graph['dpi'] = 120
G.add_node(1,label=r"$\sigma_1$",shape = 'circle')
G.add_node(2,label=r"$\sigma_2$",shape = 'circle')
G.add_edge(1,1,headport='nw',tailport='sw',label='sp')
G.add_edge(2,2,headport='se',tailport='ne')
G.add_edge(1,2,label='1-sp')
labels = {node:G.node[node]['label'] for node in G.nodes()}
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, labels=labels)

import pylab
pylab.savefig('tmp.png')
```

[image]

(note --- the self edge isn't appearing here, but I think you know how to fix that.)

---

I think the reason that your final block of code outputs a blank screen is because of this known bug (not networkx's fault) [pylab/networkx; no node labels displayed after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865975/pylab-networkx-no-node-labels-displayed-after-update).  If you save the figure the labels will be there.

Comment: Hiyas, and thanks for the input. I haven't tagged it as an answer, as the code you've provided is a far cry from the figure I'm trying to imitate (see top).